# in what way const expression and const differ?

Tags: c++

in my c++ book this is written and there is an error on the second `new_sz()` that says:function call must have a constant value in a constant expression.

```
constexpr int new_sz(){return 42;}
constexpr int foo=new_sz();  //ok:foo is a constant expression.
```

but when it is:

```
constexpr int new_sz(){return 42;}
const int foo=new_sz();
```

there is no error . what I want to know is that do `constexpr` an `const` differ? if so: how can I deal with that error?
it is said in my book: here we defined `new_sz` as a `constexpr`.the compiler can verify_at compile time_that a call to `new_sz` returns a constant expression, so we can use `new_sz` to initialize our constexpre variable , foo. 
but there is still an error although in book it is right.

Comment: The const in your second function declaration is completely superfluous as prvalues of const scalar type are adjusted to have non-const type (as described by [expr]/6).

Comment: Consider `const int f() {return time(NULL);}` vs `constexpr int f() {return time(NULL);}`